# CMD doesn't run in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile contains the following..

```
ENV APP_HOME=/app/foo-service
CMD [$APP_HOME/start-foo-service.sh]
```

What is wrong in the above syntax, since the following runs fine

```
CMD ["/app/foo-service/start-foo-service.sh"]
```

Comment: Is the lack of quotes in the first code-block a typo?

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"$APP_HOME/start-foo-service.sh\": stat $APP_HOME/start-foo-service.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.

Comment: using CMD ["$APP_HOME/start-foo-service.sh"]

Comment: Refer the above mentioned question, its duplicate.